# I keep getting an 'illegal start of expression' and I don't know why

Tags: java, netbeans

As it is says in the title I get an illegal start of expression in my code at the equation portion. I do believe I put everything in right,  but I still get an illegal start of expression.

```
public class FacebookUsers 
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      int  months = 1;

      for ( int people = 500000000; people < 2000000000; months ++)
      {
          people = (peoplestart) * ((1.05)**(months));
      }

      System.out.println("It took "+months+" to reach one billion users on "
              + "facebook at the rate of 5% growth.");
      months = 1;
      for ( int people = 500000000; people < 2000000000; months ++)
      {
          people = people * ((1.05)**(months));
      }
      System.out.println("It took "+months+" to reach two billion users on "
            + "facebook at the rate of 5% growth.");

   }

}
```

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: what equation portion. I see at least 4 "equations" in there.

Comment: need to compile, don't use hardcoded values, can't read

Comment: This is not a candidate for closing, at least not as "not a real question". Maybe duplicate, if someone can find one.

Answer (score 9):

Java has no `**` operator. Use `java.lang.Math.pow`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: You have the right idea but it's `java.` _lang_ `.Math`